# Why is Django not pulling from session? Also .get funtion no longer lights up as the .all function does? Nothing displays from database

Tags: python, django, function, view

`` `from django.shortcuts import render,redirect, HttpResponse`
`from user_login_app.models import User`
`from .models import Book,Author,Rating`
`from django.contrib import messages`
def index(request):
`user=User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])`===================================================On this line the get function isn't operating I can no longer pull from session and the function doesn't light up the way it did.  I also get no user display on the page. Normally the .get function highlights as the .all function does, also displays the logged in user on the page.  No I get nothing from Session. To be clear, I also made all migrations. I have items in my database. I just can't pull them out.  As I have in the past. 

`author=Author.objects.all()`

`rating=Rating.objects.all()`My context statment no longer renders anything. I double checked it agianst past projects.  those were all written very similarly. 
`context={`
    `'users':user,`
   `' authors':author,`
   `'ratings':rating,`

  }
return render(request,'book_home.html',context) ``

I don't get why my .get function doesn't work?? I hope someone has an answer to this puzzle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StackOverflow community; please read this help page to ask better questions. Please share the errors you get and pay more attention to add a snippet; for example, you can see your preview of your question before you post it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
 from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

 session = Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key)
 user_id = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
 user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
 .....(rest of your code and context)
 return ......
```

i didn't test the code, here you could take a look at https://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/12/04/get-user-from-session-key-in-django/,